# Return first of each ID in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structured as following:

[image: schema diagram]

I'm trying to select the latest handicap for each player, and is therefore sorting by date and playerId.

Consider the  following query:

```
SELECT h.id, h.playerId, h.amount, h.date
FROM hancicap h
WHERE h.date < '2012-06-11'
ORDER BY h.playerId ASC, h.date DESC
```

Which yields a result such as following:

[image: example data]

*(the underlined rows are the ones I'd like to return)*

My first thought was to add a `GROUP BY h.playerId`, but that results in wrong value. I'm completely stuck and would appreciate all suggestions and thoughts!

*Wasn't sure what I was supposed to name the thread. An edit to make the name more correct would be great.*

Comment: I think the title made sense (I've suggested an edit that removes tag data from it though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery to filter out the latest rows:

```
select  *
from    players p1
where   p1.id =
        (
        select  id
        from    players p2
        where   p2.playerId = p1.playerId
        order by
                date desc
        limit   1
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Joins are always faster if you define them on key (already has indexes).

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   hancicap a 
       LEFT JOIN hancicap b 
              ON a.playerId = b.playerId 
                 AND a.date < b.date 
                 AND ( a.date < '2012-06-11' 
                        OR b.date < '2012-06-11' ) 
WHERE  b.playerId IS NULL
```

Comment: With that b.playerId IS NULL condition you just filter out everything I think ...

But you have to filter for the maximum date element somewhere, which is missing from your query.

Comment: @CsabaBenko, The condition a.date < b.date will do the job for you. It's a tricky implementation with joins to achieve good performance and avoid sub/nested queries.

Comment: Interesting solution. With your changes in it it really works. I learned something today too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT h.id, h.playerId, h.handicap, h.date
FROM handicap h
WHERE h.date < '2012-06-11'
    and h.date = (SELECT max(h2.date) FROM handicap h2
                    WHERE h2.date < '2012-06-11' and h.playerId = h2.playerId)
```

My test data was:

```
id          playerId    handicap    date
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           2           2012-06-05
2           1           3           2012-06-07
3           1           1           2012-06-08
4           1           12          2012-06-13
5           2           1           2012-06-09
6           2           4           2012-06-01
7           2           5           2012-06-10

(7 row(s) affected)

id          playerId    handicap    date
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
7           2           5           2012-06-10
3           1           1           2012-06-08

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: My first version was wrong unfortunately. Now I'm tested this new one before post. :)